# sqlsrv_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource

Tags: php, sql-server-2008

To sum it all up, I am working on an project which includes.

MSSQL server 2008, ISS 7, PHP

I want to use $_SESSION but when I use it this appears in the logging of ISS7

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: Username in line 14
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: Afdeling in line 15
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: Mail in line 16
```

Here is the script for those errors:

```
session_start();
include_once("connect.php");

if (isset($_POST['username'])) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $tsql = "SELECT id, username, afdeling, mail FROM dbo.login WHERE         username='" . $username . "' AND password='" . $password . "'";
    $res = sqlsrv_query($conn, $tsql);
    $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($res, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);
    if ($row) {
        $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
        $_SESSION['username'] = $row['Username'];
        $_SESSION['afdeling'] = $row['Afdeling'];
        $_SESSION['mail'] = $row['Mail'];
        header("Location: calender.php");
    } else {
        echo "login information is incorrect please try again.";
    }
}
```

And the page connect.php contains this:

```
$serverName = "TEST"; //serverName\instanceName
$connectionInfo = array("Database" => "TEST", "UID" => "bla", "PWD" => "bloo");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);

if ($conn) {
    echo "<span style='color:green;'>Connection established.</span><br />";
} else {
    echo "<span style='color:red;'>Connection could not be established.</span><br />";
    die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
?>
```

The script containing the post function:

```
echo "<form class='Login' action='TF.php' method='post'></br>
Username: <input type='text' name='username' STYLE='width:200px';/>&nbsp;<br />
Password:&nbsp;  <input type='password' name='password' STYLE='width:200px;'     />&nbsp;<br />
<input class='loginbutton' type='submit' name='submit' value='Log In' />
```

how can i fix these errors?
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Write this for checking the error `$res = sqlsrv_query($conn, $tsql); OR die(sqlsrv_errors());`.

Comment: Debug using `var_dump($row);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a `print_r($row);` just after the `sqlsrv_fetch_array()` call to check what `$row` contains exactly.

I guess you have a case sensitivity issue with your array indexes (`$row['Username']` not being the same as `$row['username']` or `$row['USERNAME']`).

Comment: Output: Array ( [id] => 0 [username] => Martin [afdeling] => IT [mail] => Martin@gmail.com )

Answer (score 0):

you have lowercase names in your query but you have the first letter uppercase in the row:

query:

```
SELECT id, username, afdeling, mail
```

$row :

```
$_SESSION['username'] = $row['Username'];
$_SESSION['afdeling'] = $row['Afdeling'];
$_SESSION['mail'] = $row['Mail'];
```

So this should be:

```
$_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
$_SESSION['afdeling'] = $row['afdeling'];
$_SESSION['mail'] = $row['mail'];
```